# How to do deformations in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv

I am interested in how to deform the image, for example, there is a photo 1000x1000, at the point 500 400, I want to inflate how it can be done with plastic in Photoshop.

I do not have a code, because I did not find the right one.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [remapping](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/remap/remap.html). Here's a quick demo, but note that you'd have to know the exact distortion function to duplicate Photoshop's functionality

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import math
img = cv.imread('kit.jpg')

right_eye = (215,105)
radius = 30
power = 1.6 # >1.0 for expansion, <1.0 for shrinkage

height, width, _ = img.shape
map_y = np.zeros((height,width),dtype=np.float32)
map_x = np.zeros((height,width),dtype=np.float32)

# create index map
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width):
        map_y[i][j]=i
        map_x[i][j]=j

# deform around the right eye
for i in range (-radius, radius):
    for j in range(-radius, radius):
        if (i**2 + j**2 > radius ** 2):
            continue

        if i > 0:
            map_y[right_eye[1] + i][right_eye[0] + j] = right_eye[1] + (i/radius)**power * radius
        if i < 0:
            map_y[right_eye[1] + i][right_eye[0] + j] = right_eye[1] - (-i/radius)**power * radius
        if j > 0:
            map_x[right_eye[1] + i][right_eye[0] + j] = right_eye[0] + (j/radius)**power * radius
        if j < 0:
            map_x[right_eye[1] + i][right_eye[0] + j] = right_eye[0] - (-j/radius)**power * radius

warped=cv.remap(img,map_x,map_y,cv.INTER_LINEAR)
cv.imwrite('warp.jpg', warped)
```

[image: kit.jpg]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, I just can’t understand what value to regulate the force and direction of displacement

Comment: Sorry, my previous solution wasn't  parametrized. Changed my code to use exponentiation function for displacement, so you can regulate it's radius and strength.

Comment: Thanks. The last thing I would like to know is how to do this deformation more smoothly, now it works well, but I would like to get the effect of a lens and stretching

Comment: Not sure. You can save map_x and map_y as channels of an image and open them in Photoshop to get better idea what it is doing.

Comment: @zteffi I know it's an old question but can you please explain the math behind your function? and what is the right function for the blue transformation that the author of the question asked and I would like to understand the math behind it. thanks!

Comment: @roy-amoial Since a parabola `y = x^p` will go through points [0,0] and [1,1] for all positive `p` values, you can scale this part of the parabola to the radius and use `p` as a parameter. Not sure which functions photoshop uses, but [krita](https://docs.krita.org/en/reference_manual/brushes/brush_engines/deform_brush_engine.html) has similar functionality and is open source so you can check out their solution.

Comment: Here I would also propose to use remap in combination of scipy.interpolation. You can define FFD grid within scipy splines and then render it into map1 and map2 for remap call.